# Prevent dplyr from joining on NA's

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to do a full-join of 2 df's.  To my surprise, dplyr's default behavior is to join on NA's if they exist in both df's.  Is there a functionality to prevent dplyr from doing this?

Here's an example with inner join:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(5, NA, 9), b = 1:3)
y <- data.frame(a = c(5, NA, 9), c = 4:6)
z <- dplyr::inner_join(x, y, by = 'a')
```

I would like z to contain only 2 records, not 3.  Ideally, I want to do this without having to manually filter out the records with NA's beforehand and then append them to the result (since that seems clumsy).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `na_matches = "never"`.  This is in the [NEWS](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md#joins) for v. 0.7.0 but I don't see it in the documentation.  The default is `na_matches = "na"`.

This returns two rows instead of three:

```
dplyr::inner_join(x, y, by = 'a', na_matches = "never")

  a b c
1 5 1 4
2 9 3 6
```

Comment: Very helpful. I'm surprised that matching by NA's is the default behavior, disagree with the logic.

Comment: You can find info on `na_match` in the documentation about the method `?dplyr::join.tbl_df` as this argument is only for data.frame

Comment: @cderv, I see the mention of 'see the method documentation for details of individual data sources' in the ?dplyr::inner_join help, but how would we know to navigate to ?dplyr::join.tbl_df to find out about the na_matches argument?

Comment: I wish the docs that @cderv mentioned had examples that use `na_matches` argument...