# dplyr left_join matching NA

Tags: r, dplyr

When joining data.frames along a key, and one key has a missing value (NA), my intuition was that rows with an NA key should have no match in the second data.frame. To my surprise, if there are NAs in both data.frames, dplyr matches them as if they were values.

This is extra confusing because this was discussed at length on the issues in the dplyr repository [see here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2033) and it seems to be solved! If so, I'm not seeing how this is the correct solution ; or perhaps I'm missing something

I'm using dplyr `0.7.4`

```r
t1 <- data.frame(a = as.character(c("1", "2", NA, NA, "4", "2")), b = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
t2 <- data.frame(a = as.character(c("1", "2", NA)), c = c("b", "n", "i"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
t1
#>      a b
#> 1    1 1
#> 2    2 2
#> 3 <NA> 3
#> 4 <NA> 3
#> 5    4 4
#> 6    2 5
t2
#>      a c
#> 1    1 b
#> 2    2 n
#> 3 <NA> i
left_join(t1, t2, by = "a")
#>      a b    c
#> 1    1 1    b
#> 2    2 2    n
#> 3 <NA> 3    i
#> 4 <NA> 3    i
#> 5    4 4 <NA>
#> 6    2 5    n
```

When in fact I would have expected the following:

```r
#>      a b    c
#> 1    1 1    b
#> 2    2 2    n
#> 3 <NA> 3 <NA>
#> 4 <NA> 3 <NA>
#> 5    4 4 <NA>
#> 6    2 5    n
```

Comment: What is your expected.  In the link you provided, there is a comment `Yeah, an NA should never match another NA`.

Comment: Good call; i just edited the question to show what seems like the "right" result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent dplyr from joining on NA's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161553/prevent-dplyr-from-joining-on-nas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use the argument `na_matches = "never"`. This was pointed out by [Dani Rabaiotti](https://twitter.com/DaniRabaiotti/status/966288198308638721) and [Hadley Wickham](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/966287168577687552) on twitter.

This argument is documented in the `left_join` method for the `tbl_df` class: `?left_join.tbl_df`

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is the same as `merge` (although with some reordering).

```
merge(t1,t2,all.x=T)
     a b    c
1    1 1    b
2    2 2    n
3    2 5    n
4    4 4 <NA>
5 <NA> 3    i
6 <NA> 3    i
```

You can get your expected output by setting `incomparables=NA`:

```
merge(t1,t2,all.x=T,incomparables=NA)
     a b    c
1    1 1    b
2    2 2    n
3    2 5    n
4    4 4 <NA>
5 <NA> 3 <NA>
6 <NA> 3 <NA>
```

In `dplyr` this option doesn't appear to be documented, but looking at `dplyr:::left_join.tbl_df` you can see `na_matches` looks promising. Some playing around reveals you need to give it the value `"never"`.

```
left_join(t1,t2,by="a",na_matches="never")
     a b    c
1    1 1    b
2    2 2    n
3 <NA> 3 <NA>
4 <NA> 3 <NA>
5    4 4 <NA>
6    2 5    n
```

Comment: Thank you! in my dplyr documentation it explicitly describes the `na_matches="never"` argument. Just wanted to leave this in a comment in case future readers want to read more. They can get this via `?join.tbl_df`