# Identify records which fulfill complex join conditions with NA value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have a data frame with 3 columns, namely `node1`, `node2` and `cluster` which was extracted from `getLinkCommunities` in `linkcomm` package in `R`. Here is a reproductive script.

```
community <- data.frame(
  node1 = c(
    "st_sub_main_th=hira", "roo_main=2", "st_con_rt=sub-room", "roo_main=1", "roo_main=1",
    "roo_main=1", "st_sub_main_th=tsuma", "st_sub_main_th=tsuma", "st_sub_main_th=tsuma",
    "st_th=hira", "st_th=hira", "roo_main=1", "st_th=hira", "st_th=hira", "st_con_rt=main-room",
    "st_con_rt=main-room", "st_con_tr=terrace", "roo_main=4", "roo_main=4", "roo_main=4",
    "roo_main=4", "st_th=tsuma", "st_th=tsuma", "st_sub_main_th=hira", "st_sub_main_th=hira",
    "st_sub_main_th=hira", "st_sub_main_th=hira", "roo_main=2", "roo_main=2", "roo_main=2",
    "st_con_tr=direct", "st_con_tr=direct"),
  node2 = c(
    "st_con_tr=terrace", "st_con_tr=terrace", "st_con_tr=terrace", "st_con_tr=direct",
    "st_con_rt=sub-room", "st_adsb=add", "st_con_rt=sub-room", "st_con_tr=terrace",
    "st_adsb=add", "roo_main=1", "st_con_rt=main-room", "st_con_rt=main-room",
    "st_con_tr=terrace", "st_adsb=add", "st_con_tr=terrace", "st_adsb=add", "st_adsb=add",
    "st_th=tsuma", "st_con_rt=main-room", "st_con_tr=terrace", "st_adsb=add",
    "st_con_rt=main-room", "st_adsb=add", "roo_main=2", "st_con_tr=direct",
    "st_con_rt=sub-room", "st_adsb=add", "st_con_tr=direct", "st_con_rt=sub-room",
    "st_adsb=add", "st_con_rt=sub-room", "st_adsb=add"
  ),
  cluster = c(
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
  )
)
```

On the other hand, I have an original data frame which was used for association analysis.

```
df <- data.frame(
  isstilt = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA),
  st_con_rt = c(
    "sub-room", "main-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", NA, "main-room",
    "main-room", "main-room", "main-room", NA, "sub-room", "sub-room", "main-room", "sub-room",
    NA, NA, "main-room", "sub-room"
  ),
  st_con_tr = c(
    "direct", "terrace", "direct", "direct", "direct", "direct", NA, "direct", "terrace", "direct",
    "terrace", NA, "terrace", "direct", "terrace", "terrace", NA, NA, "direct", "terrace"
  ),
  st_th = c(NA, "hira", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "tsuma", "tsuma", "tsuma", "tsuma", NA, NA, NA, "hira", NA, NA, NA, "hira", NA),
  st_adsb = c("add", "sub", "sub", "add", "add", "sub", NA, "add", "add", "sub", "add", NA, "add", "add", "add", "add", NA, NA, "add", "add"),
  st_sub_main_th = c("tsuma", NA, "hira", "hira", "hira", "other", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "hira", "hira", NA, "tsuma", NA, NA, NA, "hira"),
  st_sub2_main_th = c(
    NA, "hira", "tsuma", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "hira", NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  roo_main = c(3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 4)
)
```

`node1` and `node2` in `community` contains some of columns in `df` at the left of the equal sign and choices at the right of the equal sign. I want to join `cluster` information to `df` based on those conditions, but it seems quite complicated for me.

I suppose the basic process may be like this:

1. Convert wide to long format
   Bind `node1` and `node2` into one column `rule`
2. Convert (split) `rule` into two columns (`element` and `choice`)
   For instance, st_sub_main_th=hira will be split into `st_sub_main_th` and `hira`.
3. Compare two data frames and add `cluster` to `df`
   Check all `element` and `choice` by `cluster` and add cluster number to `df` if it meet all conditions by cluster. Now I cannot imagine how to implement it.
   For instance, `cluster=1` contains following 6 conditions.

   element        choice
   st_sub_main_th hira
   st_con_tr      terrace
   roo_main       2
   st_con_tr      terrace
   st_con_rt      sub-room
   st_con_tr      terrace

I need to add `1` to new `cluster` column to corresponded rows in `df`.

The 1st and 2nd operation will be done by this:

```
community <- community %>% pivot_longer(-cluster, names_to="node", values_to="rule") %>%
    select(-node) %>% separate_wider_delim(rule, "=", names=c("element","choice")) %>% data.frame()
```

Now I got a table which contains conditions for joining.

```
> community
  cluster st_sub_main_th st_con_tr roo_main st_con_rt st_adsb st_th
1       1           hira   terrace        2  sub-room    <NA>  <NA>
2       2           <NA>    direct        1  sub-room     add  <NA>
3       3          tsuma   terrace     <NA>  sub-room     add  <NA>
4       4           <NA>      <NA>        1 main-room    <NA>  hira
5       5           <NA>   terrace     <NA> main-room     add  hira
6       6           <NA>   terrace        4 main-room     add tsuma
7       7           hira    direct        2  sub-room     add  <NA>
```

And I tried `superkey` approach based on the comment as well as the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77674471/r-comparison-between-columns-in-two-data-frames-to-add-value-from-specific-colu/77674645#77674645).

```
df %>% select(-building) %>% mutate(cluster = {
    match(
      do.call(paste, .),
      com %>% mutate(across(-cluster, ~ if_else(is.na(.x), "", .x))) %>%
        {do.call(paste, select(., -cluster))}
      )
    }) %>% mutate(cluster=as.factor(cluster)) %>%
      cbind(df_com %>% select(building)) %>% select(building, everything())
```

I also tried more simple approach.

```
## Extract columns in data frame
    col <- comunity %>% select(-cluster) %>% colnames()
    
    ## Join
    df %>% left_join(com, by=setNames(col, col), na_matches="never")
```

The first approach returned `NA` for all records and the latter approach found some matches but did not work as expected.
One issue is that `community` data frame contains `NA` in some rows, but it does NOT mean that the corresponded `element` should be `NA` in `df`. This `NA` indicates that this column should be omitted from comparison process.

I appreciate your suggestions.

**EDIT**

I suppose I could solve the issue thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483890/dplyr-join-na-match-to-any).

```
community %>%
      ## Split into single row data frame
      split(seq(nrow(.))) %>%
      ## Select columns without NA and inner join
      map_dfr(~ select_if(.x, ~ !any(is.na(.))) %>%
              inner_join(df,.)) %>%
      ## Select columns
      select(building, cluster) %>%
      ## Right join with original data frame
      right_join(df, by="building")
```

Comment: One approach is to create a "super key" that summarizes all the key/value pairs for element and choice. This super key would be unique for each cluster. Then in the end you can "join" the two data.frames by these super keys. This assumes that the conditions all must match exactly, and where there are missing elements in one data.frame it should match missing elements in the other (no extra elements in either data source). If helpful can provide an example of how this might look.

Comment: @Ben Thank you, I edited the post to clarify what I need. The issue is that `NA` in `community` data frame does not mean corresponded columns in `df` is `NA`. `NA` should be omitted from comparison process. I cannot find solution to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See answer below and see if this gives the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to use `community` data.frame to include the specific rules to match on. In other words, if your `df` has extra information not found in `community` for a given cluster, then it should still match and join.

If that is true, you could try something a bit different. For the `community` data, remove duplicates and include an additional column to indicate the required number of matches for that cluster.

Also, for your `df` data, remove missing values, and include a `row_number()` column to track rows and reassemble your wide data in the end.

Then you can join these two data sources by `element` and `choice`. Then, you can `filter` and keep results where for a given `cluster` and row there are enough matches found across the required rules. The output will include the matched choices found as well.

Please let me know if this gives the desired results.

```
library(tidyverse)

com_key <- community %>%
  pivot_longer(-cluster, names_to = "node", values_to = "rule") %>%
  select(-node) %>%
  separate(rule, into = c("element", "choice"), sep = "=") %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  distinct(element, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(match = n()) 

df_key <- df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-rn, names_to = "element", values_to = "choice", values_transform = as.character) %>%
  drop_na(choice)

left_join(df_key, com_key, by = c("element", "choice"), relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  drop_na(cluster) %>%
  group_by(rn, cluster) %>%
  filter(n() == match) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(rn, cluster), names_from = element, values_from = choice) %>%
  arrange(rn)
```

**Output**

```
      rn cluster st_con_rt st_th roo_main st_con_tr st_adsb st_sub_main_th
   <int>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>         
 1     2       4 main-room hira  1        NA        NA      NA            
 2     4       7 sub-room  NA    2        direct    add     hira          
 3     5       2 sub-room  NA    1        direct    add     NA            
 4     9       6 main-room tsuma 4        terrace   add     NA            
 5    11       6 main-room tsuma 4        terrace   add     NA            
 6    13       1 sub-room  NA    2        terrace   NA      hira          
 7    14       7 sub-room  NA    2        direct    add     hira          
 8    15       4 main-room hira  1        NA        NA      NA            
 9    15       5 main-room hira  NA       terrace   add     NA            
10    16       3 sub-room  NA    NA       terrace   add     tsuma         
11    19       4 main-room hira  1        NA        NA      NA
```